# How to solve 3D Printing Artifacts?

Tags: modeling, workflow, sculpting, subdivision-surface, 3d-printing

I'm having a trouble with 3D printing. I do not own a printer and I'm sending to someone for printing. So, the problem is, when they open the model to print, it appears like in the image, with lots of polygon artifacts. Does anyone know the cause of this?

I made the model with sculpting and it's highly polished. Even if I set shade flat it won't have those levels of faces. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Here goes the images of the sword inside blender.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what does the mesh look like (wireframe)?

Comment: @Timaroberts, I added the wireframe and the model visualization as well.

Comment: It looks like the result of a decimate modifier set to "planar". Don't know if it helps at all, maybe you have one attached that gets applied on export?

Comment: There is no modifier to apply :(

Comment: send your client a simple Pyramid (total of 5 verts) see if the software shows it like that. if so it's your client's problem not yours!

Comment: Uh, that's nice. Gotta try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult for me to tell with these particular images, so I'm not sure whether this is the case here or not - but I have a 3d printer, and it often adds polygons to images to allow them to be printed (you then lop the polygons off after you print).  The issue is that the object being printed is still subject to gravity, so for some geometries the printer will add "supports" that allow it to be printed.